# Creating a diverging color palette with different extremity colors

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am using the Python seaborn package to generate a diverging color palette (seaborn.diverging_palette).

```
colmap=sns.diverging_palette(3.8, 206.6, s = 75, l =30, n=200)
```

By default, it is possible to define the two extremity colors using a different "hue" (H) parameter from the HSLuv scale (http://www.hsluv.org/)  these are set to 3.8 and 206.6 at the moment.

Is it also possible to define a different "saturation" (S) and "lighting" (L) value for both colors?

Comment: not possible with `diverging_palette`. But you can of course create those colors yourself, convert to RGB space (`colorsys.hls_to_rgb`) and interpolate. (That's essentially what seaborn does as well, just with equal `s`, and `l` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python implementation for HSLuv](https://github.com/hsluv/hsluv-python) to find interpolations between colors. It's exactly what you need to work in parallel with seaborn.

Install it with:

```bash
pip install hsluv
```

I know it's 3 years late, but this answer appears in the search results.